# Check whether I am in a delayed_job process or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have a Rails app in which I use delayed_job. I want to detect whether I am in a delayed_job process or not; something like

```
if in_delayed_job?
  # do something only if it is a delayed_job process...
else
  # do something only if it is not a delayed_job process...
end
```

But I can't figure out how. This is what I'm using now:

```
IN_DELAYED_JOB = begin
  basename        = File.basename $0
  arguments       = $*
  rake_args_regex = /\Ajobs:/

  ( basename == 'delayed_job' ) ||
  ( basename == 'rake' && arguments.find{ |v| v =~ rake_args_regex } )
end
```

Another solution is, as @MrDanA said:

```
$ DELAYED_JOB=true script/delayed_job start
# And in the app:
IN_DELAYED_JOB = ENV['DELAYED_JOB'].present?
```

but they are IMHO weak solutions. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Is this a method? What about sending it a flag to indicate if the job is being called from Delayed Job or not. It can just default to false, only being set when actually being called from Delayed Job. Fast and easy solution if you can't find anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's another solution (I think you mean `DELAYED_JOB=true script/delayed_job start`), but I think it is a weak solution too, because I must remember to set or unset the variable when I start the app with delayed_job or not

Comment: Is this method automatically being run when Delayed Job started? I assumed you were doing something like this instead: `user.delay.send_email` somewhere in your code. Then you could just change that line to `user.delay.send_email(true)` where the `true` signifies it is being called as part of a delayed job.

Comment: how about trying to stop (kill) the worker spawned for the process because you would know the pid of the worker spawned.. if it gives out an error of no such processes you can assume you r outside of the job..

Comment: @MrDanA the problem is that I want to know if I am in a delayed_job procss _outside_ the delayed_job method...

Comment: @Sathiish if I understood what you mean, the kill would work also if I am outside the job... but yuo gave me an idea :-) , I could check if the delayed_job pid (`tmp/delayed_job.pid`) is the same of the process where I am

Comment: Oh my bad.. I wanted to basically convey the fact that you could always chk if the pid is currently being processed or not..

Answer (score 1):

The way that I handle these is through a Paranoid worker. I use delayed_job for video transcoding that was uploaded to my site. Within the model of the video, I have a field called video_processing which is set to 0/null by default. Whenever the video is being transcoded by the delayed_job (whether on create or update of the video file), it will use the hooks from delayed_job and will update the video_processing whenever the job starts. Once the job is completed, the completed hook will update the field to 0.

In my view/controller I can do `video.video_processing? ? "Video Transcoding in Progress" : "Video Fished Transcoding"`

Comment: I use delayed_job for the same purposes; what do you use for the transcoding? I wrote a Ruby wrapper for `avconv` (http://libav.org/avconv.html) Anyway, my problem is another: I want to know if my process is the delayed_job process

Comment: I use `ffmpeg` to encode the videos. I'm using `carrierwave`, `carrierwave-video`, `delayed_job` and `carrierwave_backgrounder` to hand the upload, transcode, background processing, and sending the upload to the background processor for transcoding.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of `carrierwave-video`, thank you

Comment: I pulled my own repository for this since I needed to `qt-faststart` the MP4s. Otherwise, it forced the full video to load prior to playing. I'm not using OGV or WEBM so this worked out nicely. You can check out my repository to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.  Add a field to your class and set it when your invoke the method that does all your work from delayed job:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :in_delayed_job

   def queue_calculation_request
     Delayed::Job.enqueue(CalculationRequest.new(self.id))
   end

   def do_the_work
     if (in_delayed_job)
       puts "Im in delayed job"
     else
       puts "I was called directly"
     end
   end

   class CalculationRequest < Struct.new(:id)
     def perform
       user = User.find(id)
       user.in_delayed_job = true
       user.do_the_work
     end

     def display_name
       "Perform the needeful user Calculations"
     end
   end
end
```

Here is how it looks:

From Delayed Job:

```
Worker(host:Johns-MacBook-Pro.local pid:67020)] Starting job worker
Im in delayed job
[Worker(host:Johns-MacBook-Pro.local pid:67020)] Perform the needeful user Calculations completed after 0.2787
[Worker(host:Johns-MacBook-Pro.local pid:67020)] 1 jobs processed at 1.5578 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

From the console

```
user = User.first.do_the_work
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 101]]
I was called directly
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to know if I am in a delayed_job procss _outside_ the delayed_job method...

Comment: In do_the_work above, in_delayed_job would be nil if you came in from something other than delayed_job.  Can you expand what you mean by outside delayed job method?

Comment: Sorry @JohnNaegle, I didn't see your comment before now. I was wrong, I wanted to say I need to know if I am in a delayed job _before_ the job is started, that is when DelayedJob bootstraps the Rails app, because I need to use it in a Rails initializer. The method you suggest is correct, but is suitable only for the code loaded after the job is started.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def delayed_job_worker?
  (ENV["_"].include? "delayed_job")
end
```

Unix will set the "_" environment variable to the current command.

It'll be wrong if you have a bin script called "not_a_delayed_job", but don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about ENV['PROC_TYPE']
Speaking only of heroku... but when you're a worker dyno, this is set to 'worker'
I use it as my "I'm in a DJ"

Comment: Oh... also if you've forked your web worker to include a DJ worker (cause why not use the second web worker)... Well that worker also processes DJ's and has env set to "worker"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for delayed job, e.g. create the file `is_dj_job_plugin.rb` in the `config/initializers` directory.

```
class IsDjJobPlugin < Delayed::Plugin

  callbacks do |lifecycle|
    lifecycle.around(:invoke_job) do |job, *args, &block|
      begin
        old_is_dj_job = Thread.current[:is_dj_job]
        Thread.current[:is_dj_job] = true
        block.call(job, *args) # Forward the call to the next callback in the callback chain
        Thread.current[:is_dj_job] = old_is_dj_job
      end
    end
  end

  def self.is_dj_job?
    Thread.current[:is_dj_job] == true
  end
end

Delayed::Worker.plugins << IsDjJobPlugin
```

You can then test in the following way:

```
class PrintDelayedStatus
  def run
    puts IsDjJobPlugin.is_dj_job? ? 'delayed' : 'not delayed'
  end
end

PrintDelayedStatus.new.run
PrintDelayedStatus.new.delay.run
```